# How to crop image in image picker before upload image

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native. I want to crop image before upload image. I am following this tutorial https://reactnativecode.com/upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/#comment-5335. Now I have problem to crop image before upload. How can I implement crop function into coding? Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker which can crop the selected image in both IOS and Android. Basic example for this is

```
selectPhoto() {
    if (this.state.selectedOption === 'camera') {
        ImagePicker.openCamera({
            cropping: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            cropperCircleOverlay: true,
            compressImageMaxWidth: 640,
            compressImageMaxHeight: 480,
            freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
            includeBase64: true
        }).then(image => {
            this.setState({imageModalVisible: false})
            this.storeUploadedData(item, image);
        })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e), this.setState({imageModalVisible: false})
            });

        console.log('camera')
    } else {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
            cropping: true,
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            cropperCircleOverlay: true,
            freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
            avoidEmptySpaceAroundImage: true,
            includeBase64: true
        }).then(image => {
            this.setState({imageModalVisible: false})
        })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
        console.log('gallery')
    }
}
```

yet there is a drawback here you need to create your own popup for selecting images through camera or gallery. Other than that this component is really made of it. The whole documentation you can find in mentioned link

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have see this document before. After I try, I can't open the gallery and upload the image

Comment: if it has capture the image it will display for sure. can you share some breif code regarding this?

Comment: @Saikiran Can I upload selected image to backend server? How ?

Comment: can you share your own popup for selecting images through camera or gallery

Comment: It is just a alert from react native. you can make use of your own button in modal.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-native-image-crop-picker instead of react-native-image-picker

Comment: Thank you for your reply. react-native-image-crop-picker can upload image to server?

Comment: Yes u can crop and upload image